# Is there an error in this question on vector addition and subtraction?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, fake-proofs

Is there an error in this question?

Let **u** = $(1,0,2)$, **v** = $(2,1,0)$ and **w** = $(0,2,1)$. Compute

||**u** + **v** - **w**.||**v** = **v**

This is exactly what is in the question (even the dot after **w** which I don't know what it means).

Thanks

Comment: I get $\mathbf u + \mathbf v - \mathbf w = (3,-1,1).$ Is that what you get? With that in mind, I don't see any way to make sense of the question in the form you received it unless there was some special definition of $\|\mathbf x\|$ you were supposed to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that $$|u+v-w|=1.$$
I hope now it's clear.

Comment: I thought so too, but it isn't 1...

Comment: @Tightrope Which says that it's impossible and you can take a next problem.