# Let = (1,0,2), v = (2,1,0) and w = (0,2,1). Compute ||u + v−w.||v = v

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let  **u**= (1,0,2), **v** = (2,1,0) and **w** = (0,2,1). 
Compute ||**u** + **v**−**w**.||**v** = **v**

I do not understand how I am supposed to compute the equation if it is already put equal to **v**. I know how to compute an expression using vectors, this question just does not make sense to me and I want to know whether I am simply misunderstanding the question or whether there is actually a problem with the question. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the dot there for?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404907

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I don't know what the dot is there for @J.G. I have contacted my lecturers about this but was ignored.

Answer (score 0):

$$u+v-w =$$
$$(1+2-0,0+1-2,2+0-1)=(3,-1,1)$$

$$\|u+v-w\|=\sqrt {3^2+(-1)^2+1^2}=\sqrt {11} $$

Something is wrong in your question.